# About bounded subspace of a topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

A topological vector space $X$ is a vector space over a topological field $K$ (most often the real or complex numbers with their standard topologies) that is endowed with a topology such that vector addition $X  \times X \to X$ and scalar multiplication $K \times X \to X$ are continuous functions (where the domains of these functions are endowed with product topologies).
Now I want to show that 
**in a topological vector space, the only bounded subspace is $\{0\}$.**

Comment: What definition of bounded subspace used? [your question didn't specify a metric on $X$]